# Set Forms Label text by timer from reference

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, winforms

I'm working on a basic audio player and I want to update some GUI elements based on the progression through the song.

Next to my Form I use an AudioPlayer class, which contains a ref on the created Form.

In the playAudio function I want to start a timer, which should call updateCurrTime, when elapsed. (For reference: I'm using [NAudio](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=naudio))

The function calling the timer:

```
public bool playAudio()
    {
        if (waveOutDevice.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
        {
            waveOutDevice.Pause();
            timer.Enabled = false;
            return false;
        }
        else if(waveOutDevice.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Paused)
        {
            waveOutDevice.Play();
            timer.Enabled = true;
            return true;
        }
        else if(waveOutDevice.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Stopped)
        {
            initPlayer(mu_path);
            waveOutDevice.Play();
            timer.Enabled = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And the function to update my Form with:

```
public void updateCurrTime()
    {
        while (waveOutDevice.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
        {
            form1_ref.curr_time = (int)audioFileReader.CurrentTime.TotalSeconds;
        }
    }
```

I defined the timer like this:

```
            timer = new Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        timer.Interval = 100;
    }
```

and the OnTimedEvent like this:

```
        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        self_ref.updateCurrTime();
    }
```

I use a getter/setter structure for the label text:

```
        public int curr_time
    {
        get { return Convert.ToInt32(this.l_t_curr.Text); }
        set { this.l_t_curr.Text = value.ToString() + "s"; }
    }
```

My problem is, that I'm getting an error, because the form is created on another thread. I did my research, but tbh, I didn't understand, how to implement BackGroundWorker or other solutions in my case.

Comment: You do not need to implement `BackgroundWorker`. Use only `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` to run the GUI change in GUI thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already tried to do that, but didn't manage to get the correct syntax down. Give me a second, I'll try to insert, what I did again.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/782274/edit) you can find an example. But I recommend to search for a better example.

Comment: Thank you very much! I implemented the Invoker again and somehow it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of Julo's hint I was able to fix the issue.

```
public void updateCurrTime()
    {
        MethodInvoker methodInvokerDelegate = delegate ()
        { form1_ref.l_t_curr.Text = audioFileReader.CurrentTime.TotalSeconds.ToString(); };
        //form1_ref.curr_time = (int)audioFileReader.CurrentTime.TotalSeconds;

        //This will be true if Current thread is not UI thread.
        if (form1_ref.InvokeRequired)
            form1_ref.Invoke(methodInvokerDelegate);
        else
            methodInvokerDelegate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To update GUI from another thread, you need to use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`.

Example:

```
private void GuiUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
      GuiUpdate(sender, e);
    });
    return;
  }

  // put here GUI updating code
}
```

Difference between `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` is:

- `Invoke` stops execution of current thread until the called function ends,
- when using `BeginInvoke` the starting thread continues without interruption.

Use `Invoke` when you need result from the function, or priority update. Otherwise it is better to use `BeginInvoke`.